# Kotlin foreach to lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm trying to switch from the traditional foreach to the lambda, but to no avail.
My foreach:

```
    for (e in error.bindingResult.fieldErrors) {
        validationError.addError(e.field, e.defaultMessage!!)

    }
```

it works perfectly.
But if I do:

```
error.bindingResult.fieldErrors.forEach{e -> (validationError.addError(e.field, e.defaultMessage!!))}
```

Does not work.
Where am I wrong?
Could anyone help?

Comment: What exactly does not work as you expect? If there's a compilation error, please post the error message, too. If it's an unexpected sort of runtime behavior, please describe it.

Comment: it simply does not add the data in the list

Comment: Maybe a different change in the surrounding code causes the issue, then. The conversion by itself seems quite correct to me. If you feel anything else might have changed, that information could also help in finding the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "Hotkey", I realized that the code was right. Another programmer had changed the JSON, and there was a syntax error.
Thank you friend, you spared me a great time looking for error where there was not. Thank you =)